# How can I secure transactions made with client-side PayPal Smart Checkout buttons?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'm trying to make a Smart Checkout button in my website which is currently running 100% in client-side.

I pass an amount to the `createOrder` function, based on the contents of the shopping cart, which is client-side. Now, I know that the amount can perfectly be tampered with, and PayPal would have no way of knowing that the customer is underpaying.

We are a small group of people and expect a low volume of sales, so we wouldn't have a problem detecting these underpayments and canceling the transaction (refunding the paid amount to the customer, and not shipping the item).

However, we would still have to pay PayPal fees, so this can be easily abused into making us (the seller) lose money.

Is there any way to make client-side PayPal Smart Checkout buttons, while also protecting myself from this kind of exploits?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to make client-side PayPal Smart Checkout buttons, while also protecting myself from this kind of exploits?

This is why server-side verification is a must. It is very easy to exploit these kind of things client-side and you cannot secure it client side either. PayPal have documentation on server side implementations for verifying payments. They have many SDK's too to suit your needs. e.g. NodeJS, PHP, Python...

[PayPal Checkout Server-Side SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/setup-sdk/)

Comment: I think that I should probably don't use Express Checkout buttons altogether. I've realized that even exposing the client API key, can let a user make fraudulent payments, which can cause the same problems as the ones described in the question. After implementing back-end verification, there are still several security flaws than can easily be exploited with just the client API key of the buttons.

Comment: Express checkout buttons can be secure with server-side implementation I believe. Yes the client API key is visible but that is fine because your secret key will only be accessible server side. If your secret key becomes comprimised (sever hacked?) then yes that is a problem. But, you can create enterprise level implementations securely using server-side method with the Express Checkout buttons for sure.

Comment: the problem I saw is that with the client API key, you can create orders with just client-side Javascript. So one could, say, create orders, and then do chargebacks. How would PayPal know that these orders were created fraudulently? As far as they're concerned, it's a legitimate order. I don't fully understand how PayPal works for merchants just yet, so I don't know if this kind of situations can be abused as easily as I think.